# Obfuscate text using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm looking to obfuscate (to make obscure, unclear, or unintelligible) paragraph text. Essentially

- I need to be able to control where it starts and stops.
- I don't want people previewing the source and getting the original text where it is hidden.
- The obfuscated text needs to follow the original formatting - keeping the spacing, line breaks, capitalisation and punctuation etc.
- Alphabetical characters need swapping with another random alphabetical character.

I'm trying to hide text in an article. What would be the best way to do this using javascript?

**Example**

See the following example from the [Make book](https://makebook.io/)

[image]

Note: I came across the [baffle library](https://camwiegert.github.io/baffle/#demo) does something similar but doesn't quite do the job...

Comment: The problem is, if this is happening on the Client, the Client can see the function to decode anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a reasonable attempt at this using vanilla JavaScript, while noting the concerns in the comments of course, particularly the point that if the original text is sent to the client it will of course be available to them.

```js
let inputText = `“It Will Feed my Revenge!” To bait fish withal: if it will feed nothing else, it will feed my revenge. He hath disgraced me, and hindered me half a million; laughed at my losses, mocked at my gains, scorned my nation, thwarted my bargains, cooled my friends, heated mine enemies; and what's his reason?`;

function getRandomChar() {
   const characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
   return characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length));
}

function getReplacement(char) {
  if (/^[^a-z]+$/i.test(char)) {
      return char;
  }
  let replacement = getRandomChar();
  if (char.toUpperCase() === char) {
      replacement = replacement.toUpperCase();
  }
  return replacement;
}

function obfuscate(text, start = 0, end) {
    end = end || text.length;
    const obfuscatedSection = Array.prototype.map.call(text.substring(start,end), getReplacement).join("");
    return text.substring(0, start) + obfuscatedSection + text.substring(end);
}

console.log("Original text:", inputText);
console.log("\nObfuscated text:", obfuscate(inputText, 15, 200));
```